# Automorphism of a category sends objects to isomorphic objects?

Tags: category-theory, triangulated-categories

quick question for my better understanding:

Assume you have an additive category $\mathcal{C}$ and an automorphism $\Sigma$ of this category. Does $\Sigma$ send objects to isomorphic objects? If it doesn't in general, when can I expect it (under which reasonable assumptions) to do so? I'm asking this to clarify my understanding while reading about triangulated categories.

Comment: Consider a category with two objects $a$ and $b$, and only identity morphisms . . .

Comment: @NoahSchweber Such category is not additive.

Comment: Ok, in this case it won't work. But I ask $\mathcal{C}$ to be additive...so I,m confused: Do we allow a group structure on the empty set? I don't think so

Comment: It's easy to enlarge Noah's example to an additive example. One version of Noah's example is just the category $\text{Vect} \times \text{Vect}$ ($\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded vector spaces), with the automorphism given by swapping the two factors.

Comment: Just to note that you can get the kind of thing you're looking for from automorphisms (and autoequivalences) naturally isomorphic to the identity.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, this is very rarely true even with extremely nice hypotheses on $C$. Consider the category of $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector spaces and the automorphism $\Sigma$ which shifts the grading up by $1$. The objects $c$ such that $c \cong \Sigma c$ are the $\mathbb{Z}$-graded vector spaces each of whose graded pieces have the same dimension.

What's true is that $\Sigma c$ has the same categorical properties as $c$ (which is to say, properties that only depend on how $c$ sits inside $C$). For example, $c$ is projective iff $\Sigma c$ is projective. This is similar to how elements of, say, a ring need not be fixed by automorphisms of the ring, but two elements related by an automorphism share ring-theoretic properties such as being nilpotent.

Comment: Ah! Thanks a bunch. That clarifies things

Comment: Note that there isn't even a natural map from $c$ to $\Sigma c$ that you could ask to be an isomorphism. In general there won't be any nonzero maps between them (e.g. if $c$ is a graded vector space concentrated in a single degree).